# System seems to be crash

Tags: boot, grub2, login-screen, freeze, amd-graphics

Please help me on this problem . I couldn't find anyone of my country can solve it.
When I switch on laptop Ubuntu logo appeared and still in that way for more than 20 minutes and log in screen didn't appeared . 
Before that problem happened I was downloaded new packages in sources.list my graphics card is AMD Radeon and Intel processor with corei5
I tried to use the recovery mode to apt-update but got cannot resolve HTTP:// 
I tried to ping www.google.com but got unknown host 
Is there any destlis I can add it? 
Contents of sources.list are

```
dep http://archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse

dep-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
dep http://archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu trusty universe 
dep-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu trusty universe
```

Comment: Please note 12.04 has two months left of support. There's really no point in troubleshooting. Instead you should be using your time to assure the required backups, test and install a current release.

Comment: My release was 14.04 not 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Two part answer.

## Part #1

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot

## Part #2

To correct the errors in /etc/apt/sources.list...

Do the **Part #1** file system check, but don't do the `reboot` command. Instead, add the following...

- type `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
- type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
- change all references of `dep` to `deb`
- save and quit gedit

  - don't manually edit sources.list in the future
- reboot

Comment: thanks for your solution . your solution came late for me . i copied my data and re-install Ubuntu from scratch . i hope your solution may be useful for someone later . thanks again

Comment: Can you help in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/881884/desktop-only-appeared

Answer (score 0):

You're idea is fine to enter recovery mode. From there you need first to make sure network connectivity is working.
Please check with

```
ifconfig -a
```

if you can see a proper network device.
To get an ip address and resolver (DNS) configuration just use the following command:

```
dhclient eth0
```

In this example we assume that eth0 is the right device. If you can use an Ethernet connection your life will be more easy. If you are lucky to see a Wireless Network Device it is also okay.
After that you should be able to use apt.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replying. I found eth0 wlan0 l0 . I was using wireless connection before the problem happened. So should I write dhclient wlan0?

Comment: Yes. after that you should have a configure network connection.

Answer (score -1):

In your case i'd suggest following things.

1. If you can start recovery mode.
    First thing, Backup your important data by coping it to USB.
   Second thing, plug in Ethernet and run following command

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

2. If can't start recovery mode. You gotta reinstall Ubuntu. Make bootable USB and wipe all previous data and install new Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for replying I make this solution in the last step . But I think that someone can solve it without reinstalling. Contents of sources.list seems not be right. And also AMD graphics can be a problem as I read but don't know how can I figure it